# InvalidCastException, DLLs and reflection trouble in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, interface, .net

I'm trying to use a precompiled DLL with reflection, to instantiate an interface for my class that is in the DLL. I tried by the book, but it won't work. It throws InvalidCastException when I try to do something like:

```
ICompute iCompute = (ICompute)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Where type of course is my class that implements ICompute interface. I'm stuck and don't know what to do. The complete code follows:

This is the DLL content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    public class ClassThatImplementsICompute : ICompute
    {
       public int sumInts(int term1, int term2)
       {
           return term1 + term2;
       }

       public int diffInts(int term1, int term2)
       {
           return term1 - term2;
       }
    }
}
```

The actual program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{

    public interface ICompute
    {
        int sumInts(int term1, int term2);
        int diffInts(int term1, int term2);
    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loading dll...");
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("mylib.dll");

            Console.WriteLine("Getting type...");
            Type type = assembly.GetType("ConsoleApplication18.ClassThatImplementsICompute");
            if (type == null) Console.WriteLine("Could not find class type");

            Console.WriteLine("Instantiating with activator...");
            //my problem!!!
            ICompute iCompute = (ICompute)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            //code that uses those functions...



        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Is `ICompute` declared twice? Once in each assembly? If so, that is your problem. Just because two interfaces have the same members does not make them the same interface.

Comment: Did you try to use .NET 4 and dynamic? If iCompute is dynamic, then it might work.

Comment: @vcsjones 
At first I thought the same then recompiled my dll in this way:
    csc /target:library /reference:Program.exe /out:mylib.dll ClassThatImplementsICompute.cs

First time I done it probably wrong way:
   csc /target:library /out:mylib.dll Program.cs ClassThatImplementsICompute.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to do with how you load the assembly with `Assembly.LoadFrom()`.

`LoadFrom()` load the assembly into different context compared to context of the `ICompute` interface you are trying to cast to. Try to use `Assembly.Load()` instead if possible. i.e. put the assembly into the bin / probing path folder and load by the full strong name.

Some references:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx (see the disadvantage bit for LoadFrom)

Comment: Is the assembly which has the ICompute interface signed? For it to cast correctly. ICompute interface needs to be coming from the same assembly, same physical file same location with the same strong name. I have not try something similar without strong name so I am not sure about the behaviour of unsigned assemblies.

Comment: Well, actually I don't know if I understand what you're asking. Sorry, I'm relatively new to C#. I created 2 files with exactly content above. My ICompute interface definition is in the Program.cs file and the ClassThatImplementsICompute in ClassThatImplementsICompute.cs file. I compiled with command line csc Program.cs then ClassThatImplementsICompute.cs referencing Program.exe for interface definition. Exact command: **csc /target:library /reference:Program.exe /out:mylib.dll ClassThatImplementsICompute.cs**. It worked. Then I just moved mylib.dll to Debug in VS and ran it.

Comment: I might not know how to do it and I have no good reference for that so my only hope is to ask real coders, people that know.

Comment: Are you sure the csproj file actually not signing Program.exe (which make it a different assembly compared to just doing CSC Program.cs). I tested a few times with CSC only and your code works (in .NET 4.5).

Comment: Actually you're right and that's strange. I recompiled it as you said and it works. Now, I'm trying to understand what happened and why. I still don't know what signing means but I'll search for it.

Comment: If you have some other ideas about what happened please let me know. Thanks! You helped me a lot!